# springboot thymeleaf form with jquery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf bootstrap form which I want to submit data using ajax but I keep having this error in the console. Which points to my entity class but there is nothing wrong with my entity class.

Entity class with constructor, getters and setter omitted

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "subjects")
public class Subjects {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer id;

String name;

@Column(name = "subject_code", nullable = false, length = 5, unique = true)
String code;
```

controller class

```
@Controller
```

public class SubjectController {

```
@Autowired
SubjectService subjectService;


//handler method that show form
@GetMapping("/subjects/new")
public String showSubjectForm(Model model) {
        
    Subjects subject = new Subjects();
        
    model.addAttribute("subject", subject);
        
    return "redirect:/subjectList";
}

//handler method that saves subjects
@PostMapping("/subjects/save")
public String saveSubject(Subjects subject) {
    
    subjectService.saveSubject(subject);
    
    return "redirect:/subjectList";
}
```

}

HTML file that contains bootstrap modal form and ajax code to submit the data

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            contextPath = "[[@{/}]]";
            $(document).ready(function() {
                requestURL = contextPath + "subjects/save"

                $("#saveButton").on("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    submitFormNew();

                });
            });

            function submitFormNew() {
                //reads the values of the fields
                name = $("input[name='name']").val();
                code = $("input[name='code']").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : requestURL,
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data : JSON.stringify({
                        "name" : name,
                        "code" : code
                    }),
                    
                    success : function(data) {
                        
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            };
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{../fragments/main_layout}">
<head th:replace="fragments :: page_head('subjects','none')">

</head>
<body>

    <div layout:fragment="content" class="main-container">

        <div class="card cardspace">
            <div>
                <button type="button"
                    class="form-control w-25 btn btn-secondary mb-2"
                    id="link-add-subject" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#newSubject" href="">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="row ms-auto">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="coursecode">Course Code</label> <input type="search"
                                    class="form-control" id="coursecode">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pt-3">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="card cardspace">

            <div class="card card-body">

                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th scope="col">Subject Code</th>
                            <th scope="col">Subject Name</th>

                            <th width="50px"></th>
                            <th width="50px"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr th:each="subject:${subjects}">
                            <td th:text="${subject.code}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${subject.name}"></td>
                            <td><a href="#"><span class="btn btn-primary fa fa-edit">Edit</span></a></td>
                            <td><a href="#"><span
                                    class="btn btn-primary fa fa-trash-alt">Delete</span></a></td>
                        </tr>



                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal fade text-center" id="newSubject">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">New Subject</h4>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn-close"
                            aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form onsubmit="return submitForm();" id="newForm">

                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <div class="row g-3 align-item-center ">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <label class="col-form-label">Subject Code:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group m-auto">
                                <div class="row g-3 align-item-center ">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <label class="col-form-label">Subject Name:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveButton">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error as shown in the console

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.sms.common.entity.Subjects.code
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy124.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy124.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy128.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.sms.admin.subjects.SubjectService.saveSubject(SubjectService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sms.admin.subjects.SubjectController.saveSubject(SubjectController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: This error is thrown from Hibernate. Probably "code" field gets null. Make sure you're posting the correct data. Just put console.log(code); before your ajax call and see what the value is. Also, it makes sense to add some validation to the form since you have the required field.

Comment: @VictorBjorn I have fix it and thanks for your help. Another question is there a way to reload the table with newly inserted data from the database without refreshing the entire page. I have fellow a lot of code on the web but non is working

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it. The problem is because I am not using a `RestController` I modified the code by removing `dataType`, `contentType` and `JSON.stringify` and it works.

```js
contextPath = "[[@{/}]]";

$(document).ready(function() {
  requestURL = contextPath + "subjects/save"

  $("#saveButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitFormNew();

  });
});

function submitFormNew() {
  //reads the values of the fields
  name = $("input[name='name']").val();
  code = $("input[name='code']").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: requestURL,

    data: {
      "name": name,
      "code": code
    },

    success: function(data) {

      console.log(data);
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorate="~{../fragments/main_layout}">

<head th:replace="fragments :: page_head('subjects','none')">

</head>

<body>

  <div layout:fragment="content" class="main-container">

    <div class="card cardspace">
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="form-control w-25 btn btn-secondary mb-2" id="link-add-subject" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#newSubject" href="">Add</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <form action="">
          <div class="row ms-auto">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="coursecode">Course Code</label> <input type="search" class="form-control" id="coursecode">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pt-3">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="card cardspace">

      <div class="card card-body">

        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>

              <th scope="col">Subject Code</th>
              <th scope="col">Subject Name</th>

              <th width="50px"></th>
              <th width="50px"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr th:each="subject:${subjects}">
              <td th:text="${subject.code}"></td>
              <td th:text="${subject.name}"></td>
              <td><a href="#"><span class="btn btn-primary fa fa-edit">Edit</span></a></td>
              <td><a href="#"><span
                                    class="btn btn-primary fa fa-trash-alt">Delete</span></a></td>
            </tr>



          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal fade text-center" id="newSubject">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">New Subject</h4>
            <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <form>

              <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <div class="row g-3 align-item-center ">
                  <div class="col-auto">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Subject Code:</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-auto">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group m-auto">
                <div class="row g-3 align-item-center ">
                  <div class="col-auto">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Subject Name:</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-auto">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveButton">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```